# Using VueJS 2 variable in Laravel blade

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, laravel-blade

i have this blade template code

```
        <div v-if="ok" id='search-result'>
        <table class='table table-responsive thead-text' border='5'>
            <thead>
                <tr class='success'>
                    <td>{{trans('language.user_name')}}</td>
                    <td>{{trans('language.user_phone')}}</td>
                    <td>{{trans('language.user_email')}}</td>
                    <td>{{trans('language.settings')}}</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr v-for='(arrayresult ,key ,id) in arrayresults' class='warning'>
                    <td>@{{arrayresult.username}}</td>
                    <td>@{{arrayresult.userphone}}</td>
                    <td>@{{arrayresult.useremail}}</td>
                    <td class='hidden-print'>
                        <a href='/{{$path}}/users/@{{arrayresult.id}}' class='btn btn-success'>{{trans('language.show')}}</a>
                        <a href='/{{$path}}/users/@{{arrayresult.id}}/edit' class='btn btn-info'>{{trans('language.edit')}}</a>
                    </td>                       
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

now i want to add the id came from the response in the a tag 
this one

```
<a href='/{{$path}}/users/@{{arrayresult.id}}' class='btn btn-success'>{{trans('language.show')}}</a>
```

but its not working in my console i gat this

```
/project/public/users/{{arrayresult.id}}
```

and i need it to be like this

```
/project/public/users/1 or 2 or user id
```

thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind the `href` attribute using `v-bind`

```
<a v-bind:href="'/{{$path}}/users/' + arrayresult.id" class='btn btn-success'>{{trans('language.show')}}</a>
```